# Routing in Angular 4, make active Link background color change

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a sidebar like this :

```
        <li class="nav-item collapsed side" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home" ><li class="nav-item side">
            <a class="nav-link" href routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>             
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="home">

              <li class="nav-item list-unstyled"><a class="nav-link" href  routerLink="home/submenu-1">Submenu1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item list-unstyled"><a class="nav-link" href  routerLink="home/submenu-2">Submenu2/a></li>
          </ul>
        <li class="nav-item side">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="firstOption">First Option</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item side">
             <a class="nav-link"href routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="history">Second Option</a>
         </li>
```

How do I make it, that when I click on the FirstOption, the background color of FirstOption changes,showing that it is active.
Because I can navigate through the options, I just can't change the background color when the list is active.
Also, I want the sub-menu of the first home, to remain open when I have submenu1 or submenu2 open.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all delete attribute "href", it is unnecessary. If everything defined properly active link should get class "active":
routerLinkActive="active"

Comment: So I should have routerLinkActive on every anchor tag ? And then have my css defined like :
`.nav-item .active{
background-color:red;}` and it should work ?

Comment: Exactly... That's what you have to do

Comment: Thank you, It does work but the issue is that the  Home ( the first link) stays always active. When i click on others they change the background, except for the first one..

Comment: For home page use routerLink="/"

Comment: Using `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` helped with that !
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to change backcolor dropdown-menu

```
.dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #00a65a;
  outline: 0;
}
```